# How to convert a normal pdf to booklet pdf and vice versa

Tags: java

Is there is any open source java library like iText or iReport can be used to convert normal pdf to booklet pdf or vice versa?

Any java library or java program suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/create-booklet-a4-document

Comment: Thanks for the link and we can close this.